# Spring Boot and ENUMs cause An illegal reflective access operation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, enums

I am using Spring Boot, with NEO4J as the database. I am using Java 13 and Spring 2.3.1. I have an enum in my code:

```
package uk.co.osiris.entities;

public enum Involvement {
    Master,
    Charterer, 
    Owner,
    DesponentOwner,
    Agent, 
    Inspector,
    PortAuthority, 
    Other
}
```

It isn't used in an NodeEntity or RelationshipEnity. In fact this enum is simply in the class path. It's not used anywhere.

When I run the application, I get:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils (file:/home/adrian/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar) to field java.lang.Enum.name
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

I can, and for them probably will, just delete the enum.

But why do I get this?

Answer (score 0):

```
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils (file:/home/adrian/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar) to field java.lang.Enum.name
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

As far as I know this is (only) a warning of an issue in Spring when using Java 11+. Everything should still run fine for now, though, AFAIK.

Spring should fix this, however, to make sure the framework also works with future Java versions once the illegal access operations will be denied.

Consider to file an issue for the Spring framework (or check if there is already one).

Comment: Thank you.  I check, and the exact same code is OK on Java 1.8. It seems to failed from Java 11 onwards. 

I have tried to put a support comment to Springs website. That's not easy.

Comment: @AdrianChallinor: Here's the how to contribute page: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#how-to-contribute The issues are on GitHub as well: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues

Comment: @AdrianChallinor There is already an issue for this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24999

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed that this is a problem with Spring Framework using Java 9 onwards. It gives the warning message with Java 11 & 13, both OpenJDK and Oracle JDK. It seems to happen when you are using Java JPA. I happen to be using Neo4J but I suspect other databases may experience the same issue.

It is only a warning, but not one I can accept when shipping code to clients.

So, I degraded to Java 1.8 :-{